# What is p_align in elf header?

Tags: c, linux, elf

i am studying reverse engineering.

```
readelf something
Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr           PhysAddr           FileSiz  MemSiz   Flg Align
  PHDR           0x000040 0x0000000000400040 0x0000000000400040 0x0001f8 0x0001f8 R   0x8
  INTERP         0x000238 0x0000000000400238 0x0000000000400238 0x00001c 0x00001c R   0x1
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
  LOAD           0x000000 0x0000000000400000 0x0000000000400000 0x0006f0 0x0006f0 R E 0x200000
  LOAD           0x000e10 0x0000000000600e10 0x0000000000600e10 0x000220 0x000228 RW  0x200000
  DYNAMIC        0x000e20 0x0000000000600e20 0x0000000000600e20 0x0001d0 0x0001d0 RW  0x8
  NOTE           0x000254 0x0000000000400254 0x0000000000400254 0x000044 0x000044 R   0x4
  GNU_EH_FRAME   0x0005b4 0x00000000004005b4 0x00000000004005b4 0x00003c 0x00003c R   0x4
  GNU_STACK      0x000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x000000 0x000000 RW  0x10
  GNU_RELRO      0x000e10 0x0000000000600e10 0x0000000000600e10 0x0001f0 0x0001f0 R   0x1
```

in here.
What does mean Align column?

i read man(5) elf.h and some docs, but i still don't know exactly it.
and there are some questions about this in stack overflow but there aren't answer.

could explain it to me?

Comment: Might help: https://www.intezer.com/blog/research/executable-linkable-format-101-part1-sections-segments/

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Thanks. but i read it already.

Comment: That link answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Linux, type `man elf` in your terminal and read current documentation about ELF format. The field `Align` in `readelf` output is `p_align` of program header. Here is part of [online docs](https://linux.die.net/man/5/elf):

> p_align
>
> This member holds the value to which the segments are aligned in
> memory and in the file. Loadable process segments must have congruent
> values for p_vaddr and p_offset, modulo the page size. Values of zero
> and one mean no alignment is required. Otherwise, p_align should be a
> positive, integral power of two, and p_vaddr should equal p_offset,
> modulo p_align.

Comment: yeah. i read that description. but i can't understand how p_align be used.
What does mean exactly p_align value? 0x1, 0x0, 0x8, 0x200000.
0x20000 means load 0x20000 byte size?

Comment: As far as I know, it means minimal size of block for segment parts. For example, if you have Align 8 and your segment ends on offset 9 (decimal), then 10-15th bytes will be unused. Means no other segment can occupy it.